# Policy regarding questions which it’s controversial whether they should be open or closed

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review-queues

While sparked by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/88222/9682), my question pertains to a much broader swatch of posts.

Let’s say you have a post that gets closed. Five votes, off-topic. Then five people say it was closed unfairly and vote to reopen. Five more vote that really it should have remained closed, etc.

Or, a more common case that I see in the review queue, where as many as eight or nine people have voted on a question, a large percentage of which think it should be closed and a large percentage of which think it should remain open.

What is the site programmed to do in such cases? Is there a limit to how many times a question can flip between open and closed with no edits? Is there a limit to how many times a question can be closed for the same reason?

In the second case, is there a limit to how many people can vote on a question before there are too many “leave open” votes that the system removes it from the queue without closing it?

Comment: Perhaps each successive action should require an additional vote, thus making it impossible to just have a repetitive 5 vs 5 voting. I.e. 5 votes to close, 6 votes to reopen, 7 votes to reclose, etc.